# Why one definition rule (ODR) is not honoured by g++ in this case ? .

Tags: c++, header, linker, g++, redefinition

As you see, there are multiple definitions of testfn symbol while linking, but the linker takes the first occurence (in linking order) and ignores the other occurances in other libraries. 
This probably is the way how the linker works.

But Is there any way to enforce linker to flag error on seeing multiple symbols in different linked libraries ? Or any other options to catch such duplicate definitions ?

---

Content of test1.h:

```
#ifndef TEST1
#define TEST1
void testfn();
#endif
```

---

Content of test1.cpp

```
#include "test1.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void testfn()
{
cout << "file1" << endl;
}
```

---

Content of test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST
#define TEST
void testfn();
#endif
```

---

Content of test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void testfn()
{
cout << "file" << endl;
}
```

---

Content of main.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
#include "test1.h"

int main()
{
testfn();
return 0;

}
```

---

Created a shared libraries.

```
 g++ -fPIC -shared libtest1.so test1.cpp
 g++ -fPIC -shared libtest.so test.cpp
```

Created executable with library order#1

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -ltest -ltest1
```

Created executable with library order#2

```
g++ -o main1 main.cpp -ltest1 -ltest
```

Ouput of main

```
./main
file
```

Ouput of main1

```
 ./main1
file1
```

Comment: As I recall, no diagnostic is required for violating ODR.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it *is* honoring the ODR, by only taking one of the methods out of the library. And that's just the way shared libraries work.

If you want to see the compiler complain about this, link them all together, without the library step.

```
g++ -o main1 main.cpp test1.cpp test.cpp
```

So your question becomes, "How do I tell if I have two libraries which both contain a indentifier with the same name?"  Keep in mind that this is often not a problem and sometimes done intentionally.  I'd suggest running the library tool (I'm not familiar with the g++ toolset) to get listing of the libraries, and run DIFF of them.

Comment: I don't think so - "The definition can appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in the standard or *a user-defined library*". I might be wrong.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore : that's covering the "can't be defined less the once" part of it.  However, once the linker finding something to satifiy that, there is no requirement to keep looking.

Comment: I agree, ergo there's no error, but it's still breaking the rule.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: The code is breaking the rule, not the compiler.

Comment: Agree, but my point was how to catch such problems with tool (compiler) ?

Comment: @James Curran,  Thanks for your reply. For argument sake, lets consider this problem is done "unintentionally" and shouldn't the linker be flagging atleast a warning, in this case it is silently taking the symbol based on the linking order, which i think is bit dangerous..

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to get GNU ld to complain about multiple symbol definitions across shared libraries.  However, if normal static library archives are involved, you might be able to use the `--whole-archive`/`--no-whole-archive` set of options to get what you want:

For example, after building `libtest.a` and `libtest1.a` instead of the shared library versions, I get no errors with the following link commands:

```
$ g++  -o main main.cpp   -ltest1 -ltest  -L.
$ ./main
file1

$ g++  -o main main.cpp   -ltest -ltest1  -L.
$ ./main
file
```

But do get errors for the following:

```
$ g++  -o main main.cpp -Wl,--whole-archive -ltest1 -ltest -Wl,--no-whole-archive -L.
./libtest.a(test.o): In function `testfn()':
test.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `testfn()'
./libtest1.a(test1.o):test1.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not sure you would want to use `--whole-archive` for release builds - maybe only as a sanity check for possibly name conflicts (I think that using `--whole-archive` normally will increase the size of your binary for no good reason).

Also, as mentioned before, this seems to have no effect on shared libraries.